# Ionic 2 Cloud services

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've built an ionic app that uses Ionic Cloud services to subscribe to FCM Push notifications. Currently, I receive the notifications whenever it's sent.

It requires 'CloudSettings' const to be configured in the app-module.ts, where the Push configurations like sender-id, android and ios specific configuration including GCM topics could be provided.

Now, I want to subscribe to additional topics based on the user selection. How to subscribe to different topics (dynamically) with Ionic 2 Cloud Services?

As 'CloudSettings' is a constant and imported in the app module, it could not be overridden. Is there any way to override the configuration?

I tried to reset the value for push.PushOptions before registering to, but it's not working. Any solution to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `azure notificaton hubs`. They allow multiple tagging and registration for single devices.

Create a backend app to manage sending and subscriptions and register via this instead of the ionic backend.

There are lots of tutorials to support this, but ultimately once the push registration was completed and the FCM token returned,I manually registered this via my .NET backend where I can control the tags and allow them to be easily updated depending on user preferences. The backend app can then be used to broadcast notifications depending on the tags you want to receive them

Comment: Thanks @mcgowan for your suggestion to use a different backend. I'm just trying to know if there is a way to achieve this with Ionic Cloud. As everything else works with the current set-up, I thought it should be a small change to override the cloud settings. Anyways, I'll try your solution if I'm giving up with Ionic cloud.